# friend function of base class and derived class

Tags: c++, class, friend

I have a base class Fraction and a derived class iFraction. Fraction represents the improper fractions and iFraction represents the mixed fractions.

```
class Fraction {...};
class iFraction : public Fraction {...};
```

Now, I want to declare a friend function of these two class, namely convertF. The function convertF can convert the improper fractions(Fraction) to mixed fractions(iFraction). 
How cold I do this?
Actually, I'd like to declare the function like this:

```
friend iFraction convertF (Fraction &Fra);
```

However, it can't be declared within the base calss Fraction. why?

Answer (score 2):

Since `friend` relationships aren't inherited, you need to declare `convertF` as a friend of both classes. But you need this only if the function needs access the internals of these classes - are you sure the public interface of the classes doesn't suffice?

One further reason to try to avoid such a double friend is that it would create a circular dependency between these classes via the signature of `convertF`.

**Update:** This is exactly why you can't declare your friend function the way you show above. For this to work, the compiler would need to know the full definition of `iFraction` while it is still not finished with the definition of the base class `Fraction`, which is impossible.

Technically it could work the other way around, by forward declaring `iFraction`. Although I still wouldn't consider it a good solution. Are you sure your class hierarchy is right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now, I understand why I can't do this. But, how could I realise my purpose that convert Fraction to iFraction

Comment: the class Fraction has two data members, one for numerator and one for denominator. The class iFraction has one more data memeber iNum which represents the part of integer

Comment: @user1305904, after double checking the terms, now I am sure that your inheritance relationship is not right: a mixed fraction is **not** an improper fraction. Of course, conversion between the two is entirely sensible.

Comment: you may be right. This code is just for practicing my prgramming skill. thanks for your opinion anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a friend function for this. There are two ways to do this use dynamic_cast or write a conversion constructor which takes a Fraction object and converts it into a iFraction object. I am not so sure if the second option is at all a good option, but woth a try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't know what's dynamic_cast now. I am just a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/friends.html

Always try to understand the concept first.